# Bootstrap different color themes in same instance

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, sass

So I have a site and I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.7 and sass. I'm being asked to have a "dark theme" page and the ability to set different types of color themes based on certain pages.

There might be a page with white-label branding, or a dark theme, or a blue theme.

I'm being asked to keep everything else the same.

I'm thinking about having those pages add a class to the body tag that changes the CSS colors, but what are the best practices for changing all colors in a bootstrap 3.3.7 sass style controllers.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap colour code are present under variables file(bootstrap/**/_variables.scss) were we can play on it.

But when it comes to theme development best way to handle the colour is we can have separate scss for colour code,  where the folder or file structure can be followed like bootstrap or as per the developer style.